# SQL joining 2 queries that share a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2008-r2, select-case

I have 2 SQL queries that share a column called `catalogid`

Query #1:

```
Select 
   catalogid, numitems, allitems - numitems ignoreditems
from
    (select 
        i.catalogid,
 sum(case when (ocardtype in ('PayPal','Sofort') OR
                ocardtype in ('mastercard','visa') and
                odate is not null) then numitems
                else 0 end) numitems,
 sum(numitems) allitems
from orders o"
join oitems i on i.orderid=o.orderid"
join products T1 on T1.catalogid = i.catalogid"
group by i.catalogid) X
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT catalogId, ProcessedSucssessfully =
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST( b.orderid as varchar(10))
              FROM oitems b JOIN orders o ON b.orderid = o.orderid
              WHERE b.catalogId = a.catalogId
              AND (o.ocardtype in ('PayPal','Sofort') OR o.ocardtype in  ('mastercard','visa') and o.odate is not null)
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''),
                  NotProcessed =
        STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST( c.orderid as varchar(10))
               FROM oitems c JOIN orders o ON c.orderId = o.orderid
               WHERE c.catalogid = a.catalogid
               AND (o.ocardtype in ('mastercard') OR o.ocardtype is null) and o.odate is null
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM oitems a
GROUP BY a.CatalogId
```

How would you make those 2 into one query or join them?

Note I run those 2 as `SqlCommand` from vb.net

One thing to notice is i've the same conditions for both queries, what I tried doing is adding the second query parts to the select case which didn't work out

Here are the involved tables

oitems table

```
+---------+-----------+----------+
| orderid | catalogid | numitems |
+---------+-----------+----------+
| o737    |       353 |        1 |
| o738    |       364 |        4 |
| o739    |       353 |        3 |
| o740    |       364 |        6 |
| o741    |       882 |        2 |
| o742    |       224 |        5 |
| o743    |       224 |        2 |
+---------+-----------+----------+
```

orders table

```
+-----------------+------------+------------+
|         orderid | ocardtype  |   odate    |
+-----------------+------------+------------+
|     o737        | Paypal     |            | 'OK
|     o738        | MasterCard | 01.02.2012 | 'OK
|     o739        | MasterCard | 02.02.2012 | 'OK
|     o740        | Visa       | 03.02.2012 | 'OK
|     o741        | Sofort     |            | 'OK
|     o742        |            |            | 'ignore because ocardtype is empty
|     o743        | MasterCard |            | 'ignore because Mastercard no odate
+-----------------+------------+------------+
```

result from Query #1:

```
+-----------+----------+--------------+
| catalogid | numitems | ignoreditems |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
|       353 |        4 |            0 |
|       364 |       10 |            0 |
|       882 |        2 |            0 |
|       224 |        0 |            7 |
+-----------+----------+--------------+
```

result from Query #2:

```
+-----------+------------------------+--------------+
| catalogid | ProcessedSucssessfully | NotProcessed |
+-----------+------------------------+--------------+
|       353 |o737,o739               |              |
|       364 |o738,o740               |              |
|       882 |o741                    |              |
|       224 |                        |o742,o743     |
+-----------+------------------------+--------------+
```

the wanted result:

```
+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------------------+---------------+
| catalogid | numitems  | ignoreditems | ProcessedSucssessfully  | NotProcessed  |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------------------+---------------+
|       353 |         4 |            0 | o737,o739               |               |
|       364 |        10 |            0 | o738,o740               |               |
|       882 |         2 |            0 | o741                    |               |
|       224 |         0 |            7 |                         | o742,o743     |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------------------+---------------+
```

The conditions for Query1:

1. if `ocardtype` is empty then ignore the `numitems` and consider it as `0` in the sum and sum the ignored items to the `ignoreditems` column
2. if ocardtype for some order is MasterCard or Visa and the odate is empty then ignore the numitems and consider it as 0 and sum the ignored items to the `ignoreditems` column
3. if `ocardtype` is Paypal or Sofort, then just do the `numitems` sum without checking the date because those types require no `odate`

The conditions for Query2 Which are the same as Query1 but different things to be done:

1. if `ocardtype` is empty then add `orderid` to `NotProcessed`
2. if `ocardtype` for some order is MasterCard or Visa and the `odate` is empty then add `orderid` to `NotProcessed`
3. if `ocardtype` is Paypal or Sofort, then don't check for `odate` and add the `orderid` to `ProcessedSucssessfully`

The above things are done in 2 seperate queries, but I am trying to make it in to one query since they have the same conditions

Comment: @RedFilter i tried adding the parts of query 2 to the select case of query1 since they have the same conditions but with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here we go, I built out the table structure to validate the SQL.
I did not load any data but it does execute.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
Select  
   catalogid, numitems, allitems - numitems ignoreditems 
from 
    (
        select  
            i.catalogid, 
            case 
                when ocardtype in ('PayPal','Sofort') then sum(i.numitems)
                when ocardtype in ('mastercard','visa') and odate is not null then sum(i.numitems)
            else 0 end numitems, 
            sum(numitems) allitems 
        from 
            orders o
        inner join
            oitems i 
        on 
            i.orderid=o.orderid
        inner join 
            products T1 
        on 
            T1.catalogid = i.catalogid
        group by 
            i.catalogid, ocardtype, odate
    ) A
) B
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        catalogId, 
        ProcessedSucssessfully = 
           STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST( b.orderid as varchar(10)) 
                  FROM oitems b JOIN orders o ON b.orderid = o.orderid 
                  WHERE b.catalogId = a.catalogId 
                  AND (o.ocardtype in ('PayPal','Sofort') OR o.ocardtype in  ('mastercard','visa') and o.odate is not null) 
                  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''), 
                      NotProcessed = 
            STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST( c.orderid as varchar(10)) 
                   FROM oitems c JOIN orders o ON c.orderId = o.orderid 
                   WHERE c.catalogid = a.catalogid 
                   AND (o.ocardtype in ('mastercard') OR o.ocardtype is null) and o.odate is null 
                   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') 
    FROM 
        oitems a 
    GROUP BY 
        a.CatalogId 
)C
    ON 
        B.CatalogId = C.CatalogId
```

Comment: Now if you want to make it a stored procedure...

add to the top of the sql
create procedure usp_procedure_name
(
@OID VARCHAR(50)
)
AS

Then add a where clause to each part of the sql

Comment: Thank you really much, all fine now :)

Answer (score 2):

You could create a view on the sql box and then just Linq to that view

```
select * from table_a inner join table_b on table_a.field_a = table_b.field_b
```

EDIT:

or

```
Select * from (select * from table_a inner join table_b on table_a.field_a = table_b.field_b) AB
inner join
select * from (select * from table_c inner join table_d on table_c.field_c = table_d.field_d) CD
ON
AB.id_column = CD.id_column
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @thor both queries share the same conditions but i am not sure how i can add the second Query#2 part to the select statment in Query#1, tried doing it but got syntax errors

Comment: can you script the tables involved and put the SQL up

Answer (score 1):

SQL server view would look something like this

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    Select  
       catalogid, numitems, allitems - numitems ignoreditems 
    from 
        (
        select * from
        (
            select  
                i.catalogid, 
                sum(case when (ocardtype in ('PayPal','Sofort') 
                OR 
                ocardtype in ('mastercard','visa') and odate is not null) then numitems 
                else 0 end) numitems, 
                sum(numitems) allitems 
            from 
                orders
         ) o
        inner join
            items i 
        on 
            i.orderid=o.orderid
        inner join 
            products T1 
        on 
            T1.catalogid = i.catalogid
        group by 
            i.catalogid
        ) A
    ) X 
) B
INNER JOIN
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
        catalogId, 
        ProcessedSucssessfully = 
           STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST( b.orderid as varchar(10)) 
                  FROM oitems b JOIN orders o ON b.orderid = o.orderid 
                  WHERE b.catalogId = a.catalogId 
                  AND (o.ocardtype in ('PayPal','Sofort') OR o.ocardtype in  ('mastercard','visa') and o.odate is not null) 
                  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''), 
                      NotProcessed = 
            STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST( c.orderid as varchar(10)) 
                   FROM oitems c JOIN orders o ON c.orderId = o.orderid 
                   WHERE c.catalogid = a.catalogid 
                   AND (o.ocardtype in ('mastercard') OR o.ocardtype is null) and o.odate is null 
                   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') 
    FROM 
        oitems a 
    GROUP BY 
        a.CatalogId 
) B
ON A.CatalogId = B.CatalogId
```

Comment: thank you so much, but it gives me syntax error near ) and near on, i think its because we have 24 '(' and 25 ')'                                                            )(31,1) expected token:Unknown
)(31,1) expected token: 
ON(54,1) expected token:; JOIN ( )

Comment: Could be, I did not validate against the the table structure. Sorry for the slow response. I had to cut and run early yesterday.

Comment: not a problem thank you for taking time to write it,i've been trying to find what is wrong with the syntax but couldn't figure it out